# Django Middleware Error - Middleware changed for 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Whenever I run my local server with my django project I am getting a warning and an error message saying that in Django 1.7 the global middleware classes were changed - even though I am using 1.8. My blog, at http://127.0.0.1:8000/, loads fine, but when I try to load the admin site I get `AttributeError at /admin/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`, which as far as I can tell is to do with the Middleware. Thanks for your help in advance

EDIT: My middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Error message:

```
Warnings
?: (1_7.W001) Middleware_Classes is not set.
    Hint: Django 1.7 changed the global defaults for the middleware_classes. django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware, django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware, and django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware, were removed from the defaults. If your project needs this middleware then you should configure this middleware.
```

Comment: We can't help because you haven't included your middleware settings or the full error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MIDDLEWARE` setting was introduced in Django 1.10. If you are using Django 1.9 or earlier it will have no effect, and you should be using the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting instead.

Make sure you are using the correct version of the docs (e.g. [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/), [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/)), so that you follow the correct instructions.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong - I created it using 1.8 and I don't remember changing it!

Answer (score 5):

I created my project using `django 1.11` but when I transferred the files to the web server, I encountered errors with `fcgi` which forced me to downgrade to `1.8`. Therefore the error came up because admin was now expecting `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`
instead of 
`MIDDLEWARE`. 
Changing that solved the error.