# PyInstaller Django compilation <frozen importlib._bootstrap>

Tags: python, django, compiler-errors, compilation, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my django Project With PyInstaller, cuz of be safe in a shared disk driver That every One can review My Code.

and when Compile I get this output:

**(env) D:__DEV__>pyinstaller Chortke/manage.py --onedir**

```
222 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0+46286a1f4
222 INFO: Python: 3.7.4 (conda)
222 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
222 INFO: wrote D:\__DEV__\manage.spec
222 INFO: UPX is not available.
239 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\__DEV__\\Chortke', 'D:\\__DEV__']
239 INFO: checking Analysis
239 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
239 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
244 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
256 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6561 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6664 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6679 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
required by c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\python.exe
7249 INFO: Analyzing D:\__DEV__\Chortke\manage.py
7307 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
7311 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\mab\\.conda\\envs\\env\\lib'
8887 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
8887 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\mab\\.conda\\envs\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
15264 INFO: Processing module hooks...
15264 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
15264 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.cache.py"...
15439 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.mail.py"...
15601 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.management.py"...
15634 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'tkinter'
15635 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'IPython'
15635 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'matplotlib'
15635 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.py"...
17084 WARNING: Hidden import "django.db.backends.__pycache__.base" not found!
17084 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
File "<string>", line 36, in walk_packages
File "<string>", line 36, in walk_packages
File "<string>", line 20, in walk_packages
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\options.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 43, in <module>
    % '", "'.join(lib_names)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
19403 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
24054 INFO: Packages required by django:
['sqlparse', 'pytz']
24054 INFO: Django root directory D:\__DEV__\Chortke\chortke
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\subproc\django_import_finder.py", line 37, in <module>
    list(settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS) + \
File "c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'
25398 INFO: Collecting Django migration scripts.
31358 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
31458 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
32433 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
32433 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
32433 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
32449 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
32452 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
32452 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
32454 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module PIL.ImageQt
32455 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
32458 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
32458 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
32458 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
32460 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
32462 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
32462 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
32934 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
33011 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
33134 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
33136 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
33136 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
33137 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
33208 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
33307 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
33307 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
33307 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
33307 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
33579 INFO: checking Tree
33579 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
33579 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
33663 INFO: checking Tree
33663 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
33663 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
33683 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.mysql.base.py"...
33697 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.oracle.base.py"...
33806 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
33894 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
33900 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
33901 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_django.py'
33907 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
34271 INFO: Looking for eggs
34271 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\python37.dll
34271 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
34271 INFO: Warnings written to D:\__DEV__\build\manage\warn-manage.txt
34435 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\__DEV__\build\manage\xref-manage.html
34710 INFO: checking PYZ
34710 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
34710 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\__DEV__\build\manage\PYZ-00.pyz
35823 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\__DEV__\build\manage\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
35874 INFO: checking PKG
35875 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
35875 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
35896 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
35904 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\mab\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
35904 INFO: checking EXE
35904 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
35905 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
35905 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\__DEV__\build\manage\manage.exe
36000 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
36014 INFO: checking COLLECT
36015 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
36015 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
134331 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

And When i Run the exe file, I get this Error:

**(env) D:__DEV__>dist\manage\manage.exe runserver**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
File "threading.py", line 870, in run
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
File "D:\__DEV__\dist\manage\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
File "site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
File "site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
File "site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
File "site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_admin_select2'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
File "site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
File "site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
File "site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
File "D:\__DEV__\dist\manage\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
File "site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
File "D:\__DEV__\dist\manage\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
File "D:\__DEV__\dist\manage\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
File "pathlib.py", line 1346, in exists
File "pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
[5108] Failed to execute script manage
```

Plugins that installed:

**(env) D:__DEV__>pip freeze**

```
altgraph==0.16.1
astroid==2.2.5
backports.csv==1.0.7
certifi==2019.6.16
colorama==0.4.1
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20181111
Django==2.2.4
django-admin-rangefilter==0.5.0
django-admin-select2==1.0.1
django-import-export==1.2.0
django-jalali==3.1.0
django-modeladmin-reorder==0.3.1
django-nested-admin==3.2.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
Faker==1.0.7
future==0.17.1
isort==4.3.21
jdatetime==3.2.0
jdcal==1.4.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
mccabe==0.6.1
odfpy==1.4.0
openpyxl==2.6.2
pefile==2019.4.18
Pillow==6.1.0
PyInstaller==4.0.dev0+46286a1f4
pylint==2.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-monkey-business==1.0.0
pytz==2019.2
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==5.1.2
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
tablib==0.13.0
text-unidecode==1.2
typed-ast==1.4.0
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.11.2
xlrd==1.2.0
xlwt==1.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In my system i used to downgrade the django version from 2.2 to 1.8 in pyinstaller 3.4 version(pyinstaller 3.5 leads to kind of numpy error). Afterwards this error was resolved.

Refer this link 
[Django Middleware Error - Middleware changed for 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340811/django-middleware-error-middleware-changed-for-1-7)